How can I remove a placed call with TelecomManager.placeCall()?
I am working on an application that can manage calls. And the call provider platform is Twilio. But there is an issue when I make an outgoing call using TelecomManager.placeCall(). It works for the first call after application is started. But when I end this call and try to make another one the previous call stays still alive and I am not able to kill it programmatically. When placeCall() is called it shows a dialog saying Placing new call will remove your CallApp call..
I read the source code from TelecomManager.java and saw endCall method which is Deprecated. And documentation does not give any information on how to remove the existing call programmatically.
How can I remove call everytime user hangs up?

After reading the documentation I found a piece of code that I had missed before. Basically the Connection object returned by ConnectionService.onCreateIncomingConnection should be destroyed using Connection.destroy. Otherwise, the call remains in the system alive.
